# Unexpected StackOverflow with ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Code:

```
interface IModule
{
     string Title{get; set;}
}

interface IModularizedStructure
{
     ReadOnlyCollection<IModule> Modules {get;}
}

class ModularizedStructure: IModularizedStructure

{
     List<IModule> _modules;
     public ReadOnlyCollection<IModule> Modules 
     {
         get
         {
             return Modules;
         }
         private set
         {
             Modules = value;
         }
     }
     public ModularizedStructure ()
     {
         _modules = new List<IModule>();
         Modules = new ReadOnlyCollection<IModule>(_modules);
     }
}
```

I acquire `StackOverflow` error in `Modules private set;` while trying to `Modules = new ReadOnlyCollection<IModule>(_modules);` and I can't understand the cause of it. I suspect that it's somehow linked with interfaces, but can't figure out how exactly.

I've find a solution that allows me get behavior that I need:

```
interface IModule
{
     string Title{get; set;}
}

interface IModularizedStructure
{
     IList<IModule> Modules {get;}
}

class ModularizedStructure: IModularizedStructure
{
     List<IModule> _modules;
     public IList<IModule> Modules 
     {
         get
         {
             return _modules.AsReadOnly();
         }
     }
     public ModularizedStructure ()
     {
         _modules = new List<IModule>();
     }
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't compile. After performing minimal changes to make it compile, it doesn't fail (I can create an instance of the class). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet I was just about to say... beat me to it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
 List<IModule> _modules;
 public ReadOnlyCollection<IModule> Modules 
 {
     get
     {
         return Modules;
     }
     private set
     {
         Modules = value;
     }
 }
```

You are accessing the getter (and the setter) of `Modules` from itself. That leads to an endless recursion and ultimaptely to a `StackOverflowException`.

What you want to do is this:

```
 List<IModule> _modules;
 public ReadOnlyCollection<IModule> Modules 
 {
     get;
     private set;
 }
```

This will work with your existing constructor code.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But before I changed something this code always throws me "You should implement this as get and set are not abstract, virtual and so on..."